# Decidability of a Turing machine always halting in at most ten steps

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I've exam comping up soon and I need help with this.  Consider the problem:

> Given a Turing machine $M$, determine if $M$ halts in at most ten steps on every input.

Is this decidable? Prove your answer.

Comment: Think finite...

Comment: Try computing $M$ to ten steps. Has it halted?

Comment: @Alex: Using which input? [One has to realize that there are infinite inputs]

Comment: @boumol There are only $2^{10}$ ones which make a difference here though, which is the point of Arthur's answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If a Turing machine halts in at most ten steps, then it can read at most ten cells from the input tape.

Comment: It seems to me that you are suggesting that the problem is decidable. However , I am afraid that this problem is not decidable (the trouble of your naive approach is "on every input"). The undecidability is a trivial consequence of Rice's Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem (since the property "halts in at most ten steps on every input" is a non trivial one).

Comment: @boumol: Read the 4th paragraph of the "Introduction" section of the Wikipedia article you linked to.

Comment: @Fischer: You are completely right about my misinterpretation of Rice's Theorem. However, I still do not see how you want to deal with all inputs: cannot be the case that a particular Turing machine halts in 10 steps for all inputs of length smaller or equal than 10, while it does not halt in 10 steps for an input of larger length?

Comment: @boumol: If a TM halts on all inputs of length $\leq 10$ in at most $10$ steps, it can be shown that its behaviour on any input — including computation length — is completely determined by the first $10$ symbols of the input (at each point in the first $10$ steps of the  respective computations the TM will be in the same state scanning the same symbol).